# Displaying posts that have comments with Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

I have Posts and Comments tables. They have belongs_to and has_many relation. Everything works great.

What I need to do is writing the SQL to pull posts that have comments. How can I do that in the controller?

I need some sort of Join I guess. Right?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Post.joins(:comments)` by itself will give you all those post that do have comments related.

The `INNER JOIN` does that work. When you use an inner join between two tables it returns a new set of data with all of the instances of the join where the condition was met, the rows are ignored otherwise.

Comment: wow! that was simple! Thank you for the explanation as well. I learnt something very useful from you today 